# Getting Error when using AFNetwork to call a post API

Tags: ios, afnetworking, instagram

I am trying to call a POST API on Instagram using AFNetworking, and my code to call is:

```
void (^mySuccessBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSDictionary* userInfo = (NSDictionary*) responseObject;

    if (block != nil) {
        block(userInfo, nil);
    }
};

void (^failureBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Request Error: %@", error);

    if (block != nil) {
        block(nil, error);
    }
};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableDictionary *param=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSString * token =[defaults objectForKey:ACCESS_TOKEN];
[param setValue:token forKey:@"access_token"];

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/%@/likes" , globalMediaId];
[manager POST:url parameters:param success:mySuccessBlock failure:failureBlock ];
```

But I am getting this error:

> request Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response
>   Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7fb4c9698e00
>   {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL:
>   https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/853150485752748330_1509614005/likes
>   } { status code: 400, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Language" = en;
>       "Content-Length" = 114;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Mon, 29 Jun 2015 05:55:33 GMT";
>       Expires = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
>       Pragma = "no-cache";
>       "Set-Cookie" = "csrftoken=f4b5426f69b154c60e6785ba52100a09; expires=Mon, 27-Jun-2016 05:55:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/";
>       Vary = "Cookie, Accept-Language"; } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/853150485752748330_1509614005/likes,
>   com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226d65 7461223a
>   7b226572 726f725f 74797065 223a224f 41757468 50617261 6d657465
>   72457863 65707469 6f6e222c 22636f64 65223a34 30302c22 6572726f
>   725f6d65 73736167 65223a22 4d697373 696e6720 61636365 73735f74
>   6f6b656e 2055524c 20706172 616d6574 65722e22 7d7d>,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}

Does anyone know why I'm getting this?

Comment: Are you sure the access token is supplied as a url parameter as opposed to in the http body ?

Comment: Yes I am sure access token is ok.

Comment: Maybe your `globalMediaId` is wrong.

Comment: No nothing is wrong, Instagram have blocked my ClientId. I have requested them for permission hope it will be resolved soon.